# How to find the largest integer $n$ for which $n!$ can be expressed as the product of $n - 3$ consecutive integers

Tags: factorial

I need to find the largest integer $n$ for which $n!$ can be expressed as the product of $n - 3$ consecutive integers. Example: $7! = 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 10 $

Comment: The product of $n-3$ consecutive numbers is always divisible by $(n-3)!$ and thus you want $\binom{K}{n-3} = n(n-1)(n-2)$ for some $K$. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: What to prove ?

Comment: What, precisely, is the statement you want to prove? It isn't clear, although the question in general is quite nice, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $(n+1)\times n \times \dots \times 5 > n!$ for $n\geq 24$. So we must have $n\leq 23$.

On the other hand $(23+1)\times 23 \times \dots \times 5 = 23!$ . So the answer is $23$, like the Miley Cyrus song.

Answer (score 2):

$n=23$ has an answer.

Given that $\binom{K}{n-3} = \frac{K(K-1)\cdots(K-(n-2))}{(n-3)!}$ this means you want a $K$:

$$\binom{K}{n-3} = n(n-1)(n-2)$$

Now, $\binom{K}{n-3}$ is an increasing function as $K$ increases.

And we have:

$\binom{n}{n-3} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} < n(n-1)(n-2)$ and $\binom{n+1}{n-3} = \frac{(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)}{24}> n(n-1)(n-2)$ when $n+1>24$. So you only have to check  the cases $n\leq 23$.

Comment: the other solutions are 7! = 7*8*9*10 ; 6! = 8*9*10 ; 4! = 24.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $n!>n!/3!$. Now
$$
n!<(n+1)!/4! \Leftrightarrow 24=4!<n+1,
$$
i.e., $n>23$. Therefore it is enough to check manually the cases $n\le 23$.

$\bullet$ $n!=(n+1)!/4!$ has solution $n=23$. This is obviously the largest.